# How do I keep part of an object stationary?

Tags: animation

I have a question that I feel like has a simple answer but I haven't really found anything on this yet.

I'm just trying to animate this object so that when the center bar moves, the end of the supports touching the bar moves with it but the other end of the supports stay in place.

[image]

I thought maybe bones were the answer but I wouldn't have a clue how to arrange these bones to achieve my goal.

Any advice?

Comment: Hello, how is the long bar supposed to move? On Z (up and down only)? On XY (can' move up and down)? On XYZ?

Comment: @moonboots it should only be moving on XY

Comment: I couldn't quite get the bone stuff to work but I found the addon AnimAll really useful as I could animate the shape of the mesh on the fly

Comment: @Confused_User: it is always helpful if you write a bit about your blender experience so that the answer fits to your needs. Something like: i started Blender yesterday, i rigged my first character or i am working for Pixar now for 25 years as chief animation officer

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Create this simple 3 bones setup:

Bone B is child of bone A (connected).

Bone C has a copy rotation bone constraint, targeting bone A.

Bone B has a Dumped track bone constraint, targeting the tail of bone C.

Now, rotating the bone A (master control bone) will cause the rig to behave as expected.

Comment: I'm unable to add a damped track constraint to bone B, maybe because it's connected to bone A

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem to add  a damped track constraint.  A common mistake is to add an object constraint to the whole object (the armature) instead of a bone constraint to the single bone (use the bone constraint properties tab in pose mode, the blue one with a bone and a circular constraint icon).

Answer (score 1):

If as you say the long bar can only move on XY, here is a solution close to Josh's:
Give Bone 1 a *Copy Rotation* constraint with Bone 2 as *Target*. Parent Bone 3 to Bone 2, but disable the *Inherit Rotation* option. Rotate Bone 2 to animate:

[image]

Comment: i think he is a real beginner so i guess he needs very detailed description...